# Navigating to a different (JS)View - Unable to access Router

Tags: sapui5

I have a homepage with two tiles which is working as expected. On clicking tile one, my control should navigate to "SearchProductPage".

I have the following files:

- `homepage.view.js`
- `homepage.controller.js`
- `SearchProductPage.view.js`
- `SearchProductPage.controller.js`

So when I click on the tile, I get the alert messages per code. But my code is not navigating to the `SearchProductPage.view.js`.

And when trying to access the router, it returns `undefined`.

### Views

#### `homepage.view.js`

```js
sap.ui.jsview("view.homepage", {
  getControllerName: function() {
   return "Webapp.controller.homepage";
  },
  createContent: function(oController) {
    var oTileSearchProd = new sap.m.StandardTile({
      title: "{i18n>tile_title_1}",
      press: [oController.goToProductSearch, oController]
    });
    var oTileTopRatedProd = new sap.m.StandardTile({
      title: "{i18n>tile_title_2}",
      press: [oController.goToProductAnalytics, oController]
    });
    var oTileCont = new sap.m.TileContainer({
      tiles: [oTileSearchProd, oTileTopRatedProd]
    });
    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
      title: "{i18n>app_head}",
      enableScrolling: false,
      content: [oTileCont]
    });
    return oPage;
  }
});
```

### Controllers

#### `homepage.controller.js`

```js
sap.ui.controller("Webapp.controller.homepage", {
  onInit: function() {
    var i18nPath = "i18n/i18n.properties";
    var oi18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
      bundleUrl: i18nPath
    });
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oi18nModel, "i18n");
  },

  goToProductSearch: function(oEvt) {
    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.navTo("idSearchProductPage");
  },

  goToProductAnalytics: function(oEvt) {
    var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idProductsAnalyticsPage");
    var oResourceBundle = app.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
    var url = oResourceBundle.getText("LOGIN").toString().trim();
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(url), "barChart");
    var that = this;
    that.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("idProductsAnalyticsPage");
  }
});
```

### App Descriptor (`manifest.json`)

```
{
  "_version": "1.12.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "id": "Webapp",
    "type": "application",
    "applicationVersion": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "sourceTemplate": {
      "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponentForManifest",
      "version": "0.0.0"
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5"
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
      "viewName": "Webapp.view.homepage",
      "type": "JS",
      "async": true,
      "id": "App"
    },
    "routing": {
      "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "JS",
        "viewPath": "sap.ui.Webapp.view",
        "controlId": "app",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "transition": "slide"
      },
      "routes": [
        {
          "pattern": "",
          "name": "homepage",
          "target": "homepage"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "SearchProductPage",
          "name": "SearchProductPage",
          "target": "SearchProductPage"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "ProductDetailPage",
          "name": "ProductDetailPage",
          "target": "ProductDetailPage"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "ProductAnalyticsPage",
          "name": "ProductAnalyticsPage",
          "target": "ProductAnalyticsPage"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "SearchProductPage",
          "name": "SearchProductPage",
          "target": "SearchProductPage"
        }
      ],
      "targets": {
        "homepage": {
          "viewName": "homepage"
        },
        "SearchProductPage": {
          "viewName": "SearchProductPage"
        },
        "ProductDetailPage": {
          "viewName": "ProductDetailPage"
        },
        "ProductAnalyticsPage": {
          "viewName": "ProductAnalyticsPage"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### My `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Divya Demo Project</title>
    <script
      src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js "
      id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
      data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Webapp":"./"}'
    ></script>
    <script>
      sap.ui.localResources("view");
      var app = new sap.m.App({
        initialPage: "homePage",
      });
      app.addPage(sap.ui.view({
        id: "homePage",
        viewName: "view.homepage",
        type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
      }));
      app.addPage(sap.ui.view({
        id: "SearchProductPage",
        viewName: "view.SearchProductPage",
        type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
      }));
      app.placeAt("content");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my project. everything is in JavaScript:

[image: My project folder]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample app with `JSView` and navigating on click: **https://embed.plnkr.co/qOnDlm**.
(**Update: `JSView` is deprecated** since UI5 v1.90. Use *[Typed Views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e6bb33d076dc4f23be50c082c271b9f0)* instead.)

### Main Issue

The main issue is that your application is not evaluating `manifest.json` at all. In order to fetch the descriptor in the first place, your app needs to use `sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer` and `UIComponent` with `metadata: { manifest: "json" }`. These are completely missing in your `index.html`. I.e. the app doesn't even know that there are routing settings.

A `ComponentContainer` is needed since Components cannot be added to the UI without a container. And in `Component.js`, the `metadata: { manifest: "json" }` assignment tells the framework to fetch the app descriptor `manifest.json` which will be then evaluated with all the router settings.

`ComponentContainer` can be added to `index.html` declaratively without an inline-script using the [`sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport) module. Please see the linked API reference for further guidance.

### Other Issues

There are more inconsistencies with the guidelines which should be also fixed together with the main issue.

<sub><sup>❌</sup></sub> The `neo-app.json` being in the webapp folder whereas `Component.js` isn't.
<sub><sup>✔️</sup></sub> For the proper folder structure, follow the topic *[Folder Structure: Where to Put Your Files](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/003f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a)*. I.e. `Component.js` should be inside, `neo-app.json` outside of the `webapp` folder.

<sub><sup>❌</sup></sub> Using deprecated APIs as well as calling methods without requiring modules
<sub><sup>✔️</sup></sub> Consult API reference which APIs to use instead of deprecated ones. E.g. defining controllers using `sap.ui.controller` should be [replaced with `Controller#extend`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/50579ddf2c934ce789e056cfffe9efa9).
<sub><sup>✔️</sup></sub> Require `sap/ui/core/UIComponent` first, and then call `UIComponent.getRouterFor`.

<sub><sup>❌</sup></sub> Module name prefixes mismatching with base namespace.
<sub><sup>✔️</sup></sub> For proper module registration according to the guideline, keep the [*general namespace*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/5a978fe3504e4dd39f5db0a46438ba64) consistent with the base `resourceRoot` namespace.

Also I see that the `homepage` view is assigned to `sap.ui5/rootView` too. Please [avoid that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47457769/5846045).

---

Here are some snippets incorporating the above mentioned points:

1. Given this [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSNTm.gif)..
2. In `index.html`:

   ```html
   <head>
     <!-- ... -->
     <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
       data-sap-ui-resourceRoots='{"myCompany.myApplication": "./"}'
       data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
       data-...><script>
   <head>
   <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
     <div style="height: 100%;"
       data-sap-ui-component
       data-name="myCompany.myApplication"
       data-height="100%">
     </div>
   </body>
   ```
3. In `Component.js`:

   ```js
   return UIComponent.extend("myCompany.myApplication", {
     metadata: {
       manifest: "json"
     },
     init: function() {
       UIComponent.prototype.apply(this, arguments);
       this.getRouter().initialize();
     },
   });
   ```
4. In `manifest.json`, `"sap.ui5"`:

   ```json
   {
     "rootView": {
       "viewName": "myCompany.myApplication.view.NotHomepage",
       "...": "..."
     },
     "routing": {
       "config": {
       "viewPath": "myCompany.myApplication.view",
       "...": "..."
     },
     "routes": [
       {
         "pattern": "",
         "name": "homepage",
         "target": "homepage"
       },
       "..."
     ],
     "...": "..."
   }
   ```
5. In controllers

   ```js
   sap.ui.define([ // e.g. controller/Homepage.controller.js
     "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
     // ...,
     "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
   ], function(Controller, /*...,*/ UIComponent) {
     "use strict";
     // 1. Stop using the deprecated sap.ui.controller.
     // 2. Convention: class name should be camel-case, starting with a capital letter (Homepage).
     // The same applies to all the other controllers and views.
     return Controller.extend("myCompany.myApplication.controller.Homepage", {
       goToProductSearch: function(oEvt) {
         const router = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this); // or without requiring UIComponent: this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
       },
       // ...
     });
   });
   ```
6. In JS views:

   ```js
   sap.ui.jsview("myCompany.myApplication.view.Homepage", { // e.g. view/Homepage.view.js
     getControllerName: function() {
       return "myCompany.myApplication.controller.Homepage";
     },
     // ...
   });
   ```

   <sup>**Update: `sap.ui.jsview` is now fully deprecated**. Use *[Typed Views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e6bb33d076dc4f23be50c082c271b9f0)* instead!</sup>

Since the project seems relatively small, I'd suggest to start anew using the basic SAPUI5 template:

[image: basic SAPUI5 template].

Comment: Thanks Boghyon, i can see my mistakes. As suggested i moved my manifest.json inside by Webapp and moved neo json outside the Webapp. I have also included the component container in index.html. So my root resource  is Webapp. I still see my code is not able to manifest. "Failed to load component manifest from "Webapp/manifest.json".

Comment: @Winona It's hard to debug from here without code. Try comparing your code with the [sample plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/qOnDlm) I gave in the answer, and tackle issues one by one.

Comment: @Winona I highly recommend to follow the learning path provided by the Demo Kit: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218, especially the walkthrough. It addresses all the basic rules I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should look first on the documentation

> https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.6/docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html

view:

```
 createContent : function(oController) {
        var oTileSearchProd = new sap.m.StandardTile({
        title: "{i18n>tile_title_1}",
        press : [ oController.goToProductSearch, oController]
        }); 
        return new sap.m.Page({
            title: "Title Page 2",
            content: [
                oTileSearchProd 
            ]
        });
    }
```

and controller:

```
goToProductSearch: function()  {
        var router;
        router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        return router.navTo("SearchProductPage", null);
    }
```

also i would change the route conf. in your manifest for example try to build it for you

```
   "routing": {
    "config": {
        "viewType": "JS",
        "viewPath": "sapui5.app53.view",
        "targetControl":"idPageContainer",
        "targetAggregation": "pages",
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router"
    },
    "routes": [{
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "First",
        "view": "zjs_view_53_02",
        "targetAggregation": "pages"
    }, {
        "pattern": "second",
        "name": "Second",
        "view": "zjs_view_53_03",
        "targetAggregation": "pages"
    }]
}
```

Comment: alles i am following that link. I have 4 pages actually in my project. My homepage has two tiles. Clicking on each should navigate to the respective pages. I have added all this in my router in my manifest.json.  editor->routing.
This is my component.js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
 "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (UIComponent, JSONModel) {
 "use strict";
 return UIComponent.extend("homepage.view", {
  metadata: {
   manifest: "json"
  },
  init: function () {
   UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);this.getRouter().initialize();

Comment: alles , i tried the above code in my view i was not able to add return new , it gave error . However i was able to add return router in controller but still got "TypeError: sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor is not a function".

Comment: you need to change your manifest routing.. i post a example i found. Seems legit